# AEXMLDocument loadXMLData() not working in Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I'm working with AEXML to write and read xml documents in Swift.  I have the writing working no problem.  And I have everything setup for the reading, but I can't seem to turn the saved text xml into the document object.  It only ever gets the first element and none of the children.  I've tried removing all the lines and spaces but still nothing.  The content is reading into the String just fine and I've tried converting the data back to a string and it isn't getting messed up in conversion.  Is this even possible with AEXML or am I just doing it wrong?

```
let doc = AEXMLDocument()
let content = try String(contentsOf:NSURL(string:file) as! URL)
let data = content.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
let xml = NSString(data:data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
try doc.loadXMLData(data)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the example shown at https://github.com/tadija/AEXML?

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to access the XML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I was actually using an outdated version of AEXML which clearly wasn't working anymore.  The updated code looks like this.

```
let content = try String(contentsOf:NSURL(string:file) as! URL)
let data = content.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
let options = AEXMLOptions()
let doc = try AEXMLDocument(xml:data,options:options)
```